# like button suspicious url error

Tags: url, facebook-like

I created a website on google sites, using my own domain name.  Clicking the like button (steegle.com generated) gives the error: "Sorry, this post contains a suspicious URL: Unknown error".  Any ideas on how to fix this or better code to use?

This is the code generated/used:

<img src="https://www.google.com/chart?chc=sites&cht=d&chdp=sites&chl=%5B%5BGoogle+Gadget'%3D20'f%5Cv'a%5C%3D0'10'%3D199'0'dim'%5Cbox1'b%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CF6F6F6'eC%5C0'sk'%5C%5B%22Steeglecom+-+Google+Sites+Like+Button%22'%5D'a%5CV%5C%3D12'f%5C%5DV%5Cta%5C%3D10'%3D0'%3D200'%3D32'dim'%5C%3D10'%3D10'%3D200'%3D32'vdim'%5Cbox1'b%5Cva%5CF6F6F6'fC%5CC8C8C8'eC%5C'a%5C%5Do%5CLauto'f%5C&sig=adcK6vIIXtgjrIIlMyRBX2yiuVI" data-igsrc="http://86.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=86&synd=trogedit&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhosting.gmodules.com%2Fig%2Fgadgets%2Ffile%2F110509162544058635853%2Fsteegle-google-sites-facebook-like-button.xml&up_url=www.freeeducationleague.org&up_layout=standard&up_width=&up_showfaces=false&up_action=like&up_font=arial&up_colorscheme=light&h=35&w=200" data-type="ggs-gadget" data-props="screenshot:http#58//www.steegle.com/images/facebook-like-120x60.png;url:http#58//hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/110509162544058635853/steegle-google-sites-facebook-like-button.xml;params:up_url=www.freeeducationleague.org&up_layout=standard&up_width=&up_showfaces=false&up_action=like&up_font=arial&up_colorscheme=light;align:;borderTitle:Steegle.com - Google Sites Like Button;height:35;igsrc:http#58//95.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?mid=95&synd=trogedit&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhosting.gmodules.com%2Fig%2Fgadgets%2Ffile%2F110509162544058635853%2Fsteegle-google-sites-facebook-like-button.xml&up_url=www.freeeducationleague.org;mid:95;scrolling:no;showBorder:false;showBorderTitle:null;spec:http#58//hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/110509162544058635853/steegle-google-sites-facebook-like-button.xml;up_url:www.freeeducationleague.org;width:200;wrap:true;title:Steegle.com - Google Sites Like Button" width="200" height="35" style="display:inline;float:right;margin:5px 0 5px 20px;" class="igm">